# Numerical artifacts appearing ONLY on boundary of 3Dplots and not on Plot

Tags: plotting, numerical-value

I have a behavior with 3D plots I really don't understand and I would like to correct it.

I have a 2D function to plot, here is its graph with Plot3D :

[image]

We can see that on the top boundary of $\Delta I$ ($\Delta I=Log[2]-SiQ[Theta]-0.001$) I have some weird negative picks. These picks shouldn't exist, indeed they don't exist on my orignal function.

To prove it, here is the 1D plot in function of $Theta$ on this boundary, we see that the function is positive (and constant) in this area. **So here we see that the negative peaks on the boundary are not due do the function I plot in itself, because when I plot this same function in 1D graph on this boundary, I don't have those negative peaks**

[image]

What is my Plot3D doing ? Is it just an artefact of visualisation ? How to get rid of this ?

Even more weird : I see that my peaks in this specific example are negative (and I know that my function is positive). So I can modify my plot3D to only display positive values. **But it still shows me some non asked negative values :**

[image]

**I want to get rid of these artefact peaks in a general way, I don't want to use the fact I know my function is positive to do it**

Also, I took a look at : [Artefacts in 3d plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63931/artefacts-in-3d-plots) but I don't think it helps me because in my case I don't have the problem on a 1D graph. E

My code (I tried to reduce it at the maximum, the example is slightly different from the one I had before my edit) :

```
H2[x_] := If[x != 0, If[x != 1, (-x)*Log[x] - (1 - x)*Log[1 - x], 0], 0]



InvH2BrancheDroite[x_] := 1 - InverseFunction[H2][x]; 

TableauValeursReciproque = Union[Table[{x, InvH2BrancheDroite[x]}, {x, 0.00001, Log[2], 0.005}], Table[{x, InvH2BrancheDroite[x]}, {x, Log[2] - 0.01, Log[2], 0.0001}]]; 

InvH2BrancheDroitePol[y_] = Interpolation[TableauValeursReciproque, Method -> "Spline"][y]; 

SiQ[Theta_] := H2[Cos[Theta/2]^2]; 

WextMaxNonDegenBruitQ[Theta_, \[CapitalDelta]I_] := 2*InvH2BrancheDroitePol[\[CapitalDelta]I + SiQ[Theta]] - 1; 

Compteur = 0; 

NbPlotPoints = 100; 


Monitor[Plot3D[{WextMaxNonDegenBruitQ[Theta, \[CapitalDelta]I], 0}, {Theta, 0, Pi}, {\[CapitalDelta]I, -Log[2], Log[2]}, AxesLabel -> {\[CapitalTheta], \[CapitalDelta]I, WextMaxNonDegenBruitQ}, TicksStyle -> Large, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 18}, RegionFunction -> Function[{Theta, \[CapitalDelta]I}, -SiQ[Theta] + 0.001 <= \[CapitalDelta]I <= Log[2] - SiQ[Theta] - 0.001], 
   ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", None, None}, PlotPoints -> NbPlotPoints, BoundaryStyle -> None, MaxRecursion -> 0, EvaluationMonitor :> (Compteur = Compteur + 1)], 
  ProgressIndicator[Compteur, {0, (2*NbPlotPoints)^2}]]

Plot[WextMaxNonDegenBruitQ[Theta, Log[2] - SiQ[Theta] - 0.001], {Theta, 0, Pi}]

Compteur = 0;

Monitor[Plot3D[{WextMaxNonDegenBruitQ[Theta, \[CapitalDelta]I], 0}, {Theta, 0, Pi}, {\[CapitalDelta]I, -Log[2], Log[2]}, AxesLabel -> {\[CapitalTheta], \[CapitalDelta]I, WextMaxNonDegenBruitQ}, TicksStyle -> Large, 
   BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 18}, RegionFunction -> Function[{Theta, \[CapitalDelta]I, z}, -SiQ[Theta] + 0.001 <= \[CapitalDelta]I <= Log[2] - SiQ[Theta] - 0.001 && z >= 0], 
   ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", None, None}, PlotPoints -> NbPlotPoints, BoundaryStyle -> None, MaxRecursion -> 0, EvaluationMonitor :> (Compteur = Compteur + 1)], 
  ProgressIndicator[Compteur, {0, (2*NbPlotPoints)^2}]]
```

Some comments on the code : in the beginning I try to find the reciprocal function on the right branch of the binary shannon entropy. This is the main function used for my plot that gives weird results.

Again I insist on the fact that these weird peaks **are not** due to numerical bad accuracy in the approximation of my inverse function to the shannon entropy because on my 1D plot I don't have the presence of the peaks. So, it is the Plot3D that is somehow reponsible for it. But I don't know why...

Comment: I guess the function `WextMaxNonDegenBruitQ` is the issue here. Is it defined beyond the boundary of the `PlotRegion`? Is it continuous there? Or does it have jumps?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher no it is well defined on this boundary. You can see it with the 1D plot that represent the value of this function on the boundary where I have my jumps on my 3D plots. This is why I find the behavior strange

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher and the second "weird" thing is that even if I force my 3Dplot to plot on a $z>0$ region, it will show me some points with $z<0$ (see the edit)

Comment: The point that I tried to make is that nobody can say anything without precise definition of the functions that involved there. And please, post them as copyable code.

Comment: This problem looks indeed quite interesting and I'm certain that Henrik, myself or others can help, but we really need code for this.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I edited with minimal code included

Comment: @halirutan I edited with minimal code included

Comment: I recommend that you use `MaxRecursion -> 5` or higher depending on how clean an image that you want. It will however be slower. You might want to also break up the axis label, e.g.,  `"WextMax\nNonDegen\nBruitQ"`

Comment: @BobHanlon yes my calculation is still quite long. I would prefer to avoid using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot3D[{WextMaxNonDegenBruitQ[Theta, ΔI], 0},
 {Theta, 0, Pi}, {ΔI, -SiQ[Theta] + 0.001, Log[2] - SiQ[Theta] - 0.001}, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", None, None}, 
 PlotPoints -> NbPlotPoints, BoundaryStyle -> None, MaxRecursion -> 1,
  EvaluationMonitor :> (Compteur = Compteur + 1)]
```

[image]

You can close the gap by using the iterator `{ΔI, -SiQ[Theta], Log[2] - SiQ[Theta]}`. With the standard number of plot points and no recursion, it's pretty fast:

```
Plot3D[{WextMaxNonDegenBruitQ[Theta, ΔI], 0},
 {Theta, 0, Pi}, {ΔI, -SiQ[Theta], Log[2] - SiQ[Theta]}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", None, None}, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  MaxRecursion -> 0] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

(The problem with `RegionFunction`, as inferred from my experience, is that it approximates the region.  The points used for evaluation can lie outside the desired domain.  With `MaxRecursion -> 0`, the error can be significant.)

*Cheap, kludgy fix:*

```
plot /. {x_Real, y_Real, z_Real /; z < 0} :> {x, y, 0.}
```

[image]

Comment: How many PlotPoints did you use here ? Because as soon as I put a maxRecursion non 0 it takes a very long time

Comment: @StarBucK I used `NbPlotPoints`. `MaxRecursion -> 0` takes 3+ sec, and at `1` it takes 6+ sec.  (I meant to post the `0` code, but going back and forth, I made a mistake.)

Comment: What I mean is that in the code you posted you didn't showed what is the value for NbPlotPoints you used :)

Comment: @StarBucK I didn't change it. (I used your code, or `100`.)

Comment: You solved my problem but I have few extra questions : So here, you think that it is probably because of an interpolation with a point further than the boundary that causes me these weird behaviors. It is possible because indeed outside of my boundary my function has probably a non physical diverging behavior. But why when I forced $z>0$ it still showed me negative peaks ? Do you have an idea ?

Comment: @StarBucK You can explore the effect of extrapolation with things like `Plot[InvH2BrancheDroitePol[y], {y, 0, Log[2](*+10^-2*)}]`. As for whether you "forced $z>0$," I'd say that the effect of the forcing depends on how the inequality is translated into code/computation. Clear (I would say clearly), it's done via an approximate numerical algorithm, maybe linear interpolation....

Comment: ...You can see the same effect here: `Plot[InvH2BrancheDroitePol[1-y],{y,0,1},RegionFunction->Function[{y,z},z>0.5]]`. I had to reverse the direction of the graph to find  an estimate outside the domain implied by `z > 0.5`. In your case, it's more complicated because of the 2D region. Along the boundary of the region, a point in the domain is determined where approximately $z = 0$.  Then the function value at the point is used. The new value is not checked to see if $z > 0$.